# Break lines in PHP are not showing

Tags: php

```
<div class="gdata">
        <h5>dis</h5>

        <h7><?= $groups[0]->grp_desc ?></h7>
```

I've been outputting comments
no break lines show from database

```
<?= $groups[0]->grp_desc ?>
```

Comment: please open `php` tags properly

Comment: whats your expected output ?

Answer (score 1):

I used this:

```
<?php echo  nl2br($groups[0]->grp_desc); ?>
```

thanks.

Comment: <h7><?php echo  nl2br($groups[0]->grp_desc); ?></h7>

Comment: For anyone reading this works because [nl2br](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) inserts HTML line break tags (`<br/>`) the string wherever it finds standard newline characters (e.g. `\n`).

Comment: glad you found the solution, but in future you should explain your answer more fully for the benefit of others. Giving some background info (such as my comment above) will help people understand, and encourage them to upvote your answer. Also, in your question it would have helped people if you'd given an example of the text you were trying to output, so that people would have understood that it was the newline characters causing the problem (and not your PHP tags, as many people assumed).

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
<div class="gdata">
    <h5>dis</h5>
    <h7><?php echo $groups[0]->grp_desc; ?></h7>
```